# Why doesn't returning 0x80000000 from a function that returns int32_t cause a warning?

Tags: c, types, casting, type-conversion, unsigned

Consider:

```
int32_t f() {
  return 0x80000000;
}
```

Why doesn't that cause a compiler warning (at least on GCC)? 0x80000000 is out of the range of `int32_t` (`INT32_MAX` is `0x7fffffff`). I believe this should cause an implicit cast - is that correct?

Further consder:

```
if (f() == 0x80000000)
  foo();
```

The above causes no warning on GCC. However

```
int32 ret = f();
if (ret == 0x80000000)
   baz();
```

Causes "warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions". I believe this is because 0x80000000 has type `unsigned int` due to being out of `int`'s range. Is that correct?

Assuming none of my assumptions are wrong, why doesn't the first comparison cause a warning?

Comment: I should clarify this is with `-Wextra`

Comment: GCC what? There have been hundreds of GCCs.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I see the same behavior with gcc 5.2.0 on 64-bit Linux.

Comment: "this is because 0x80000000 has type unsigned int due to being out of int's range" --> As a hexadecimal constant, it is of the type it first fits in between `int, unsigned, long, unsigned long, long long, unsigned long long`.  This varies between compliers/platforms.   Note: Its type has nothing to do with `int32_t`.

Comment: From a language-lawyer point of view, no warning is required in either case. But a warning for the conversion (which yields an implementation-defined result) should IMHO be enabled, if not by default then at least with `-Wall -Wextra`. Incidentally, I get a warning if I replace `0x8000000` by `2147483648`, presumably because `0x8000000` is of type `unsigned int` and `2147483648` is of type `long` (at least on my system, with 32-bit `int` and 64-bit `long`).

Comment: It's perfectly valid, and there is really no reason to warn about it: C11 draft standard `6.8.6.4 The return statement, Section 3 [...]If the expression has a type different from the return type of the function in which it appears, the value is converted as if by assignment to an object having the return type of the function.[...]`.

Comment: @EOF: Yes, but the conversion has an implementation-defined result (or, at least in principle, could raise an implementation-defined signal). No warning is *required*, but a warning would IMHO be reasonable, since the code is likely to do something other than what the author intended.

Comment: @KeithThompson: You want your compiler to warn about *every* implementation-defined conversion? I suspect you'd get tired of it quickly.

Comment: @EOF: Personally, I'd like to get a warning for this conversion in particular. Given the common wraparound semantics, the value returned is going to be `-2147483648`, which is more clearly expressed as `return INT32_MIN;`. In general, the implementation-defined conversions are ones where the source is an integer type, the target is a signed type, and the mathematical value is outside the range of the target type. I don't know that I'd want such warnings enabled by default, but I would with `-Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: @EOF: In this particular case, the value being converted is a constant, so the compiler *knows* that there's an overflow. The general case is more difficult to decide. If I convert a non-constant `long` value to `int`, perhaps I happen to know that it's in range, or perhaps I don't and it's a potential bug.

Answer (score 3):

The relevant warning switch appears to be [`-Wconversion`, which is not activated by `-Wextra`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

Comment: Did you try it yourself?  Either `-Wconversion` or `-Wsign-conversion` triggers a warning, but with gcc 5.2.0 `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` does not enable the warning.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Then the answer is "use `-Wconversion`", which I already said.

Comment: Yes, but you originally said you use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. You later deleted that line, so +1. (Even though, strictly speaking, you didn't answer the question, which was *why* gcc doesn't produce a warning by default.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: I said to give `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` a go; I didn't say it was the answer ;)

Comment: As for why GCC doesn't warn by default, if we're going to break the question down to just that, I'd say it's off-topic. It's a question for the GCC developer who made that decision; I can't see that it's answerable any other way. There's surely no useful technical reason.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: The SNR is a good reason not to warn. It's nearly impossible to use C without lots of such conversions, and you have to severely uglify/obfuscate your code with casts to avoid `-Wconversion` warnings. These casts in turn can hide bugs, so you have to do a risk/benefit analysis...

Answer (score 2):

> I believe this is because 0x80000000 has type unsigned int due to being out of int's range. Is that correct?

Yes, since it's a hexadecimal integer literal, it's type would be the narrowest of these types capable of representing the value of the literal:

- `int`
- `unsigned int`
- `long`
- `unsigned long`
- `long long`
- `unsigned long long`

Comment: The question was *why* gcc doesn't warn about the first case. I don't see an answer to that here.

Comment: Agreed, I answered the questions to which I knew the answer.

Comment: That's a good point. I'll delete my earlier (excessively snarky) comment.