# No warning when returning NULL with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, null, warnings, gcc5.2

Using `gcc` 5.2.0, I noticed that this code does not generate a warning:

```
#include <stddef.h>

int function(void)
{
    return NULL;
}

void procedure(void)
{
    return NULL;
}
```

I used the flags `-Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -pedantic` and I am running archlinux. I am not sure why this code works fine on `gcc`, especially since `clang` 3.7.0 does generate a warning.

I also tried with older versions of `gcc` like 4.9 or 4.7 and they both generate warnings.

The warnings are:

```
warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

and

```
warning: ‘return’ with a value, in function returning void
```

I should mention that I tried compiling gcc 5.2 on Debian and the result is the same. So archlinux does not seem to be the problem.

What is the rationale? I cannot seem to find anything related to this anywhere else.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610030/why-can-you-return-from-a-non-void-function-without-returning-a-value-without-pr

Comment: Lol you mean "inverse duplicate"? This question asks why you can return a value in a body of a void function. The "duplicate" asks why you can write a body of a non-void function without a return statement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't returning 0x80000000 from a function that returns int32\_t cause a warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656460/why-doesnt-returning-0x80000000-from-a-function-that-returns-int32-t-cause-a-wa)

Comment: It would help if you posted the warning message.

Comment: @juanchopanza the question was why there *isn't any* ... and it was asked before. short answer, warning will be there with `-Wconversion`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I was referring to "especially since clang 3.7.0 does generate a warning.".

Comment: Just as a matter of interest... does anyone know what the compcert compiler will do with this?

Comment: @juanchopanza I added the warnings!

@FelixPalmen `-Wconversion` did not change anything.

Comment: `-Wsystem-headers` "fixes" it, the compiler uses the wrong location for the diagnostic (the one from the macro definition). Please file a bug report in gcc's bugzilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I filled a bug report here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67730

It was confirmed and is fixed for 5.3 it seems!

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a regression in gcc 5.2.0 -- and, as far as I can tell, a weird one.

With gcc 4.4.5 and 4.8.4, the program (after adding the required `#include <stddef.h>`) produces warnings on both `return NULL;` statements, even without any extra command-line options.

With gcc 5.2.0, no warning is produced, even with `gcc -c -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -pedantic`. For the second one, which returns a value from a `void` function, a diagnostic is mandatory.

Now here's the weird part.

```
$ gcc --version | head -n 1
gcc (GCC) 5.2.0
$ cat c.c
#include <stddef.h>

int function(void) {
#ifdef USE_NULL
   return NULL;
#else
    return ((void*)0);
#endif
}

void procedure(void) {
#ifdef USE_NULL
   return NULL;
#else
    return ((void*)0);
#endif
}
$ gcc -c c.c
c.c: In function ‘function’:
c.c:7:12: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     return ((void*)0);
            ^
c.c: In function ‘procedure’:
c.c:15:12: warning: ‘return’ with a value, in function returning void
     return ((void*)0);
            ^
$ gcc -c -DUSE_NULL c.c
$
```

When `USE_NULL` is defined, no warnings are produced. Compiling with `gcc -E -DUSE_NULL` (which prints the preprocessor's output to stdout) confirms that `NULL` is defined as `((void*)0)`. But when I replace `NULL` with `((void*)0)`, the warnings are produced (as they should be).

I don't know what's going on. Once the macro `NULL` has been expanded, it should be indistinguishable from `((void*)0)`, and yet the compiler's behavior changes depending on which is used.

Comment: You probably mean 5.2.0.

Answer (score 1):

The validity of the first function is dependent on how `NULL` is defined. There's no problem with the first function if `NULL` is defined as `0`. But if it happens to be defined as `(void *) 0` (which is normally the case in C code) the first function becomes invalid. GCC is often very permissive about implicit pointer-to-integer conversions.

The second function is flat out invalid. The language specification clearly states that "A return statement with an expression shall not appear in a function whose return type is void." If it compiles, it must be another example of GCC being overly permissive about something.

You need to run GCC in `-pedantic` mode if you want its diagnostic output to be related to standard C language. In default mode it is not a credible C compiler (at least in therms of its diagnostic output) and the fact that it "does not issue a warning" means absolutely nothing.

Yet in my experiments I was not able to make GCC complain about the second function even with `-std=` and `-pedantic` switches. It looks like a bug in the compiler.

Comment: OP claims to be using `-pedantic`.

Comment: I am indeed using `-pedantic`.